# Need Help for Join tables in Linq on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

basically i am working on ASP.NET Core and I have an FromSqlRaw statement which filters and keeps some ids in a value of a talbe (ActiveCalls).
Then with Linq I filter another table of database (AppUsers).
My goal is to keep all columns of Appusers with Ids i take from ActiveCalls.

Code for SqlRaw with Ids result : (13) Correct!

```
var results = _context.ActiveCalls.FromSqlRaw("SELECT web_userid from ActiveCalls where TimeReceived>'2021-01-01' and GeoX > 23.8097593342164 and GeoX < 23.8838031312548 and GeoY > 38.1026672246045 and GeoY < 38.1607577524088 group by web_userid");
```

Code for Linq with data :Result (2281) Correct!

```
appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.LastCall >= start && s.LastCall <= end);
```

Code for Join tables to keep only Records of AppUsers based on Ids i found on ActiveCalls. Result(10) Wrong!

```
 appusers = from res in results
                     join ap in appusers
                     on res.web_userid equals ap.Id
                     select ap;
```

I have to take the result with Linq and those 3 steps and not merge all in on Sql query

Comment: I did not understand exactly. Want to summarize these three steps together in one link phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get an idea of using `FromSqlRaw` in this case.

```cs
var results = 
   from ac in _context.ActiveCalls 
   where ac.TimeReceived > DateTime.Parse("2021-01-01") 
     && ac.GeoX > 23.8097593342164 
     && ac.GeoX < 23.8838031312548 
     && ac.GeoY > 38.1026672246045 
     && ac.GeoY < 38.1607577524088
   select ac.web_userid;

results = results.Distinct();

var appusers = _context.AppUsers.AsQueryable();
appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.LastCall >= start && s.LastCall <= end);

appusers = 
   from res in results
   join ap in appusers on res.web_userid equals ap.Id
   select ap;
```

If you still does not have correct result, it means that `AppUser.Id` is not `web_userid`

Answer (score 0):

Try Somthing like this

```
var results = _context.ActiveCalls.FromSqlRaw("SELECT web_userid from ActiveCalls where TimeReceived>'2021-01-01' and GeoX >
23.8097593342164 and GeoX < 23.8838031312548 and GeoY > 38.1026672246045 and GeoY < 38.1607577524088 group by web_userid");

appusers = appusers.Where(s => s.LastCall >= start && s.LastCall <= end && results.web_userid.contains(s.Id));
```